# length: argument cannot be a symbol

Tags: maxima

I have following code:

```
configuration(s)  := makelist(i, i, 0, length(s) - 1)$
active_agents(s)  := s . configuration(s)$
prob_exp[k](l, s) := 1 - exp(- l[k] * active_agents(s))$
```

When I try to call `prob_exp` with some concrete value of `s`, for example:

```
prob_exp[k](l, [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25]);
```

I get following error message:

```
length: argument cannot be a symbol; found s
#0: configuration(s=s)
#1: active_agents(s=s)
#2: lambda([k],lambda([l,s],1-exp((-l[k])*active_agents(s))))(k=k)
-- an error. To debug this try: debugmode(true);
```

Is there a way to force passing `s` as a value?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the explanation for what you've observed: Maxima first evaluates prob_exp[k], which yields a lambda expression with two arguments, which is then applied to [l, [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25]]. Evaluating prob_exp[k] causes the error since s is not bound to the actual list.

To resolve the problem, you need prob_exp[k] to evaluate to something which can have s as a symbol. Here is one way to do that. I'll define active_agents as a simplifying function (i.e., a function which is evaluated via a simplification rule).

```
configuration(s)  := makelist(i, i, 0, length(s) - 1);
matchdeclare (aa, listp);
tellsimp (active_agents (aa), aa . configuration (aa));
prob_exp[k](l, s) := 1 - exp(- l[k] * active_agents(s));
```

Then I get:

```
prob_exp[k];
 => lambda([l,s],1-%e^-(l[k]*active_agents(s)))
prob_exp[k](l, [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25]);
 => 1-%e^-(1.5*l[k])
```

Note that Maxima prefers exact fractions to floating point numbers; I recommend using [1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4] instead of [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25].

Answer (score 0):

The simpler would be to write:

```
prob_exp(k, l, s) := 1 - exp(- l[k] * active_agents(s))$
```

The problem is function *configuration* is evaluated when you call p[k] (I don't know really why). Take a simpler example:

```
show(x):=block(disp('run),x);
q[k](x,y):=x+k*show(y);
q[k];
```

yields:

```
run
lambda([x,y],k*y+x)
```

That is, q[k] is a lambda but its contents got evaluated in the process, and it prints "run". It does not throw an error though. Why ?
Simply, you can't evaluate makelist with symbolic bounds, and length(s) is symbolic, because at this stage s has no value yet.

When you define prob_exp(k, l, s) instead of prob_exp[k](l, s), the whole expression is a lambda, and will be evaluated when all variables have a value.

Likewise, this does not evaluate *show*:

```
lambda([x,y],y+k*show(x));
```

Also, note with the preceding definition of *q*, that when calling several times q[k], *run* will be printed only once, because q is a hashed array. Thus, Maxima prepares the function (and somehow evaluates the body) on the first call, then it is stored.

Comment: More explanations on this behaviour in the old Macsyma reference, p.17 ([link]http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/mit/macsyma/MACSYMA_RefMan_V9_Dec77.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe postponing the evaluation can help?  I am not 100% sure why this works and putting e.g. the `ev(..., nouns)` into `prob_exp` does not, but this is at least a bit closer to what you need, I think.

```
kill(all);
configuration(s)  := 'makelist(i, i, 0, 'length(s) - 1)$
active_agents(s)  := s . configuration(s)$
prob_exp[k](l, s) := 1 - exp(- l[k] * active_agents(s))$

prob_exp[k](l, [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25]);
ev(%, nouns);
```